# BufferedWriter not writing everything to its output file

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedwriter

I have a Java program that reads some text from a file, line by line, and writes new text to an output file. But not all the text I write to my `BufferedWriter` appears in the output file after the program has finished. Why is that?

The details: the program takes a CSV text document and converts it into SQL commands to insert the data into a table. The text file has more than 10000 lines which look similar to following:

```
2007,10,9,1,1,1006134,19423882
```

The program seems to work fine except it just stops in the file randomly half way through creating a new SQL statement having printed it into the SQL file. It looks something like:

```
insert into nyccrash values (2007, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1033092, 259916);
insert into nyccrash values (2007, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1020246, 197687);
insert into nyccrash values (2007, 10, 9, 1
```

This happens after about 10000 lines but several hundred lines before the end of the file. Where the break happens is between a `1` and a `,`. However, the characters doesn't seem important because if I change the `1` to a `42` the last thing written to the new file is `4`, which is cutting off the 2 from that integer. So it seems like the reader or writer must just be dying after writing/reading a certain amount.

My Java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;

public class InsertCrashData
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        try
        {   
            //Open the input file.
            FileReader istream = new FileReader("nyccrash.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(istream);
            //Open the output file.
            FileWriter ostream = new FileWriter("nyccrash.sql");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(ostream);
            String line, sqlstr;

            sqlstr = "CREATE TABLE nyccrash (crash_year integer, accident_type integer, collision_type integer, weather_condition integer, light_condition integer, x_coordinate integer, y_coordinate integer);\n\n"; 
            out.write(sqlstr);

            while((line = in.readLine())!= null)
            {
                String[] esa = line.split(",");
                sqlstr = "insert into nyccrash values ("+esa[0]+", "+esa[1]+", "+esa[2]+", "+esa[3]+", "+esa[4]+", "+esa[5]+", "+esa[6]+");\n";
                out.write(sqlstr);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to close your `OutputStream` which will flush the remainder of your data:

```
out.close();
```

The default buffer size for `BufferedWriter` is [8192 characters](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#BufferedWriter.0defaultCharBufferSize), large enough to easily hold hundreds of lines of unwritten data.

Comment: @golmschenk - because the last couple of hundred lines are still in the buffer ... and won't be written until the writer is closed or flushed.  It is a **buffered** writer ...

Comment: In fact, the `FileWriter` has to perform charset encoding under the hood, which is a buffered operation on its own. Without flush or close, there can be up to 8192 pending bytes in the default setup, even without `BufferedWriter`. Since we have the year 2022 now, it’s important to point out that the preferred idiom is [the try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) rather than calling `close()` manually.

Answer (score 14):

You **must** [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29) your `BufferedWriter`. You must `close()` your `BufferedWriter` because it IS-A [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) and thus implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), which means (emphasis added) it is

> A resource that *must be closed* when it is no longer needed.

Some people say you must first call [`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush%28%29) for your `BufferedWriter` before calling `close()`. They are wrong. The documentation for `BufferedWriter.close()` notes that it "Closes the stream, *flushing it first*" (emphasis added).

The documented semantics of flushing ([`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Flushable.html#flush%28%29)) are

> Flushes this stream by writing any buffered output to the underlying stream

So, you must `close`, and `close` will flush any buffered output.

Your output file does not include all the text you wrote to your `BufferedWriter` because it stored some of that text in a buffer. The `BufferedWriter` never emptied that buffer, passing it through to the file, because you never told it to do so.

---

Since Java 7, the best way to ensure an `AutoCloseable` resource, such as a `BufferedWriter`, is closed when it is not longer need is to use automatic resource management (ARM), also known as [try-with-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739362/java7-try-with-resources-statement-advantage):

```
 try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
    // writes to out here
 } catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle ex
 }
```

You must also `close` your `BufferedReader` when it is no longer need, so you should have  nested try-with-resources blocks:

```
 try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nyccrash.txt")) {
    try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("nyccrash.sql"))) {
       // your reading and writing code here
    }
 } catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle ex
 }
```

Do not be tempted (as other answers here suggest) just to call `close()` at the end of your method,  when your code has "finished" using the writer. That will not work if your writing code throws an exception, and in particular if it throws an `IOException`.

Comment: You don’t need to nest `try` statements; a `try` statement supports more than one resource. `try(BufferedReader in = …; BufferedWriter out = …) { … } catch(IOException ex) { … }`

Answer (score 7):

> A resource that must be closed when it is no longer needed.

```
finally {
    out.close();//this would resolve the issue
    }
```

Some things to consider:

- `BufferedWriter.close()` **flushes the buffer to the underlying stream**, so if you forget to `flush()` and don't close, your file may not have all the text you wrote to it.
- `BufferedWriter.close()` also closes the wrapped Writer. When that's a FileWriter, this will **ultimately close a FileOutputStream** and tell the OS that you're done writing to the file.
- The garbage collector will automatically call `close()`, not on the BufferedWriter or the wrapped FileWriter, but on the FileOuputStream. So the OS will be happy, but you have to wait for the GC.
- However, you always want to **release OS resources** as soon as you no longer need them. This goes for open files, database connections, print queues ... anything. Trust me on this one.
- `BufferedWriter.close()` does clear up the internal character buffer, so that memory will be available for garbage collection, even while the BufferedWriter itself remains in scope.

***So, Always close your resources (not just files) when you're done with them.***

If you really want a peek under the covers, most of the Java API's source is available. BufferedWriter is [here](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.java.html).

Comment: Actually GC will close the `FileDescriptor`, not the `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not appear to be closing the writer after you've finished writing to it. Add an `out.close()` (preferably in a finally block) and it should work properly.

Comment: I cannot understand why the output is not written to the file prior to closing the `bufferedWritter`. Can you please be kind enough to teach me why that is happening

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya if you were to `close()` the `BufferedWriter` then the remaining output would be flushed to the file, the problem in this question is that the `BufferedWriter` never gets closed at all, so some of the output is still left in the internal buffer and doesn't get written to the underlying file stream.

Answer (score 5):

you dint close your BufferedWriter.close it inside a finally block

```
   finally {
    out.close();//this would resolve the issue
    }
```

Comment: I cannot understand why the output is not written to the file prior to closing the `bufferedWritter`. Can you please be kind enough to teach me why that is happening

Comment: Because of buffering. It's a `BufferedWriter`, remember?

Answer (score 1):

Always close your resources (not just files) when you're done with them.

```
 finally {
    out.close();//this would resolve the issue
    }
```

There might be situations when you want to flush the buffer without closing the file. In these situations you can use the flush-method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using BufferedWriter you can also flush the buffer when appropriate:

```
out.flush()
```

This will write the rest of the buffer to the actual file. Close-method also flushes the buffer and closes the file.

```
out.close()
```

There might be situations when you want to flush the buffer without closing the file. In these situations you can use the flush-method.

You can also use BuffredWriter's newline-method instead of adding \n to the end of the line. Newline-method uses system specific line separator so your code works on different platforms.

```
out.newLine()
```

Answer (score -2):

According to documentation it is no use calling `flush()` method. If you intent to use `FileWriter` then `flush()` would help you out.

Basically in this case, you just need to close, `BufferedWriter.close()` only. This will  flush the remainder of your data.

create finally block and put the close method inside so that it will put all data without missing.

```
 finally {
    out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Nowhere in any documentation is it stated that 'it is no use calling `flush()`'.