# java- not able to write data to file using Files.newBufferedWriter

Tags: java, file, file-io, bufferedwriter

In a java program, I am copying some text line-by-line into a string variable.

And then writing that data (again as text is retrieved line by line) into a second text file, using Files.newBufferedWriter

For some reason, the writing stops at a specific line # and col # in the second file-even though there are many more lines of text to be written. I even tried outputting messages to logs that writing is taking place at line # -- and the messages continue beyond line #892, till line #1098-- but the data is written only till line #892 in the second file.

AFAIK BufferedWriter can write data to large files- then why is this happening in my program?

For reference, the code snippets showing writing of data are given below-

```
BufferedWriter writer;
     if(outputmode.equalsIgnoreCase("append"))
        writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path_target, ENCODING,  StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
else if(outputmode.equalsIgnoreCase("overwrite"))
    writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path_target, ENCODING,  StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

And the actual code writing text (in string variable "currentline") to the file is as shown below--

```
    writer.write(currentline);
    writer.newLine();
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the write() called unconditionally? Are you closing the file? To much information missing here.

Comment: @EJP- I was not flushing the buffered writer, and not closing the file :( ... thanks anyway...

Comment: You don't need to flush it if you close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426142/java-bufferedwriter-limit-writing-is-randomly-cut-off-without-explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to [`flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush%28%29) the buffered writer to write all the contents to file.