# BufferedWriter not writing to text file

Tags: java, output, bufferedwriter

So I'm using a **BufferedWriter** and would like to write some text to a text file.

```
try {
   BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter ("/home/usr/Desktop/logger/logs.txt"));
   b.write("hello");
} catch (Exception e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
```

For some reason the text document is being created but nothing is being written to it, why is this?

Comment: You might need to close b.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BufferedWriter not writing everything to its output file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426142/bufferedwriter-not-writing-everything-to-its-output-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close `BufferedWriter`, or use `try-with-resource`

```
BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(
new FileWriter ("/home/usr/Desktop/logger/logs.txt"));
b.write("hello");

//After writing close the resource
b.close();
```